# Finding the barycenter of a triangle using complex numbers

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

My book states that:

> [image]
>
> It is known that $\vec{GA}+\vec{GB}+\vec{GC}=\vec{0}$
>
> If we draw this triangle in the complex plane and consider its points
>   as complex numbers we get:
>
> $$a-g+b-g+c-g=0\Leftrightarrow (...)\Leftrightarrow g =
>  \frac{a+b+c}{3}$$
>
> (...)

Why is $\vec{GA}$ replaced with $a-g$ in the equation? Is the vector $\vec{GA}$ the difference between the points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest way to think about this is that complex numbers correspond to vectors from the origin.  For instance, if we have a complex number $z = 13 + 8i$, then $z$ corresponds to the point $Z = (13, 8)$ which corresponds to the vector $\vec{OZ} = [13, 8]$ (where $O = (0,0)$).

With this definition in mind, we have $\vec{GA} = \vec{OA} - \vec{OG}$ which corresponds to $a-g$.  I hope that helps clear things up!

(BTW another, more intuitive way to get the formula $g = \frac{a+b+c}{3}$ is to think about the centroid as literally the average of the three points.)

Comment: Nevermind I drew it and I could understand how it works. Thanks.